# Why saying "THERE is your present." when giving it, although the present is actually HERE (in her hand), not far away)?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-structure, collocations

The following sentence is from a native english speaking lady talking about Packaged Christmas presents.

**"There is your Christmas Present."** [ITV-Is Christmas packaging worth it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Npz9TLWBZa8) (see:0:33-0:41)

When she is saying it, she makes the gesture of giving a present to someone.

As far as I know, you use **"Here is your ....."** when giving someone something, and you use **"There is your ......"** when pointing to something away from you, like pointing to a shop across the street. I also checked this again on Cambridge Dictionary. -- [Cambridge Dictionary - Here and There in front position](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/here-and-there?q=here%20there)

So, although this lady on TV is making the gesture of giving a present to someone (and clearly not pointing to something away), why does she say **"There is your present"** instead of **"Here is your present?"**

Comment: Saying 'here is...' for something that you are giving by hand is a custom, not a 'rule'. _We can use here you are and there you are (or, in informal situations, here you go and there you go) when giving something to someone. Here and there have the same meaning in this use_ [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/here-and-there)

Comment: Both are possible. Your example is an inversion, giving the location of the present and alternating with the non-inverted construction "Your present is here/there". But it is also being used to accompany the act of presenting the present to someone, so the clause has a dual role.

Comment: **there is** here has a different meaning than usual there is: There is water in the glass. It means in context (the presents shown in the program) AND due to the pronoun: This is the present for you from among the presents. Not because she is handing it to him, which could be: Here is x, for presenting it. It is not exactly the same as there is, pragmatically speaking. It's similar to: There's your winner. looking at a horse race as one horse pulls ahead.